# inbreeding coefficient calculation and genealogical software

Tags: genealogy, gedcom

I am currently looking for a piece of software which will be able to map a very large number of GEDCOM files (for around 33,000 individuals) as well as working out ancestral and individual inbreeding coefficients.  Does anyone know of any software which is capable????

Thanks

Comment: I know you asked this long ago, but if you're still here, I'm really wondering why you would need to know the inbreeding coefficient of everyone?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will find any software that does this for you, but it wouldn't be too difficult to write your own.  I would take one of the many open source gedcom parsers out there and add the individuals to a graph database such as [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/).  Once it is in Neo4j, it should be relatively easy to run your calculations on the individuals.

Answer (score 2):

GeneWeb (written in ML) handles large files very well and has fast consanguinity coefficient computing.  I believe it calculates the consanguinity coefficient for every individual in the database upon import, and it does this within a couple seconds.  It also displays arbitrarily deep ancestry and descendant trees without any noticeable lag.

http://cristal.inria.fr/~ddr/GeneWeb/en/index.html#Par

It can also handle an arbitrary number of GEDCOMs.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Pypedal](http://pypedal.sourceforge.net/) *Python Pedigree Analysis* which is a Python module that provides tools for the manipulation of pedigrees, simple visualization of pedigrees, and the calculation of measures of genetic diversity from pedigrees.